# Export and import work items from Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an application that exports and imports work items from Azure DevOps. To import work items into Azure DevOps, I have written the following code.

Would you be able to review and make suggestions? I'm unsure whether I've used the Async-Await pattern correctly.

```
namespace Export_Import_AzureDevOps.Factory
{
    public class ImportFactory : IImportFactory
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> idMapper = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
        private readonly ILogger<ImportFactory> _logger;
        private readonly Devops _devopsConfiguration;
        private readonly IImportService<WorkItemCore> _importWorkItemService;
        private readonly IImportService<SprintCore> _importSprintService;

        public ImportFactory(ILogger<ImportFactory> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IImportService<SprintCore> importSprintService, IImportService<WorkItemCore> importWorkItemService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _devopsConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(nameof(Devops)).Get<Devops>();
            _importSprintService = importSprintService;
            _importWorkItemService = importWorkItemService;
        }

        private void PublishSprints(string id)
        {
            var sprintPublishURL = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/{_devopsConfiguration.Target.TargetTeamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version={_devopsConfiguration.APIVersion}";

            var jsonPublishSprintString = $@"{{""id"":""{id}""}}";

            HttpContent publishSprintContent = new StringContent(jsonPublishSprintString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            _importSprintService.Post(sprintPublishURL, publishSprintContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private Task CreateSprints(Sprints sprints)
        {
            var sprintCreationURL = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations?api-version={_devopsConfiguration.APIVersion}";

            foreach (Sprint sprint in sprints.value)
            {
                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sprint);
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var result = _importWorkItemService.Post(sprintCreationURL, content).Result;

                PublishSprints(result.identifier);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private int GetCurrentIdEquivalentId(int oldId)
        {
            return idMapper[oldId];
        }

        private void TryAddIdMapper(int oldId, int newId)
        {
            if (!idMapper.ContainsKey(oldId))
            {
                idMapper.TryAdd(oldId, newId);
            }
        }

        private int FindParentId(WorkItemDetails workItemDetails)
        {
            var parentId = 0;

            if (workItemDetails.relations != null)
            {
                var parentRelation = workItemDetails.relations.Where(relation => relation.attributes.name.Equals("Parent")).FirstOrDefault();

                if (parentRelation != null)
                {
                    parentId = Int32.Parse(parentRelation.url.Split("/")[parentRelation.url.Split("/").Length - 1]);
                }
            }

            return parentId;
        }

        private void CreateWorkItem(string url, WorkItem workItem)
        {
            List<WorkItemOperation> operations = new List<WorkItemOperation>();
            var parentId = FindParentId(workItem.details);

            operations.Add(
                    new WorkItemOperation()
                    {
                        path = "/fields/System.Title",
                        value = workItem.details.fields.Title ?? string.Empty
                    }
                );
            operations.Add(
                    new WorkItemOperation()
                    {
                        path = "/fields/System.Description",
                        value = workItem.details.fields.Description ?? string.Empty
                    }
                );
            operations.Add(
                    new WorkItemOperation()
                    {
                        path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
                        value = workItem.details.fields.AcceptanceCriteria ?? string.Empty
                    }
                );
            operations.Add(
                    new WorkItemOperation()
                    {
                        path = "/fields/System.IterationPath",
                        value = workItem.details.fields.IterationPath.Replace(_devopsConfiguration.Source.ProjectName, _devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectName)
                    }
                );

            if (parentId != 0)
            {
                operations.Add(
                        new WorkItemOperation()
                        {
                            path = "/relations/-",
                            value = new Relationship()
                            {
                                url = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.DevOpsOrgURL}{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/{GetCurrentIdEquivalentId(parentId)}",
                                attributes = new RelationshipAttribute()
                            }
                        }
                    );
            }

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(operations);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

            var result = _importWorkItemService.Post(url, content).Result;

            TryAddIdMapper(workItem.id, result.id);
        }

        private Task CreateWorkItems(Dictionary<string, WorkItemQueryResult> workItemCollection)
        {
            foreach (var workItemCategory in workItemCollection.Keys)
            {
                var url = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/%24{workItemCategory}?api-version={_devopsConfiguration.APIVersion}";

                foreach (var workItem in workItemCollection[workItemCategory].workItems)
                {
                    CreateWorkItem(url, workItem);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task<Board> Import(IFormFile file)
        {
            string fileContent = null;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Board>(fileContent);

            await CreateSprints(board.sprints);
            await CreateWorkItems(board.workItemCollection);

            return board;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that you haven't used the Async-Await pattern correctly?

Comment: @PeterCsala - are you saying this code is fine? I want to improve code if I have to..

Comment: There are a handful of places where your code could be improved. I'm planning to post a review but it takes some time. :)

Comment: After reviewing your code in depth I have to say that you haven't used the async-await pattern everywhere where you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Url handling

Rather than recreating some URLs over and over again you can define them only once and use them multiple times:

```
...

private readonly string _versionQueryString;
private readonly string _sprintCreationURL;
private readonly string _sprintPublishURL;
private const string WorkItemPathPrefix = "/fields/";

public ImportFactory(...)
{
    ...

    _versionQueryString = $"?api-version={_devopsConfiguration.APIVersion}";
    _sprintCreationURL = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations{_versionQueryString}";
    _sprintPublishURL = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/{_devopsConfiguration.Target.TargetTeamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations{_versionQueryString}";
}
```

### `public` methods

It is a good practice to

- start with your `public` methods after the constructors
- continue with `private`/`protected` methods that are used inside the `public` methods
- finish with the helper methods that are used inside the non public facing methods

```
//Ctor
public ImportFactory(...)
//Public
public async Task<Board> Import(IFormFile file)
//Private/Protected
private async Task CreateSprints(Sprints sprints)
private async Task CreateWorkItems(Dictionary<string, WorkItemQueryResult> workItems)
private async Task CreateWorkItem(string categoryURL, WorkItem workItem)
//Helpers
private int FindParentId(WorkItemDetails details)
private HttpContent GetJsonContent(object data, string mimeType = "application/json")
```

### `Import` method

- You can use the [using declaration since C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) to simplify your code
- You can also use the `ReadToEndAsync` method of the `StreamReader` to take advantage of non-blocking I/O

```
public async Task<Board> Import(IFormFile file)
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
    string fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    var board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Board>(fileContent);

    await CreateSprints(board.sprints);
    await CreateWorkItems(board.workItemCollection);

    return board;
}
```

### `CreateSprints` method

- There is no need for the `PublishSprints` method, since the whole can be simplified to a single line

```
await _importSprintService.Post(_sprintPublishURL, GetJsonContent(new { id = result.identifier }));
```

- Since the `Post` is an async method you should `await` it
- The `GetJsonContent` helper method looks like this

```
private HttpContent GetJsonContent(object data, string mediaType = "application/json")
{
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    return new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
}
```

- After all of these modifications the `CreateSprints` looks like this

```
private async Task CreateSprints(Sprints sprints)
{
    foreach (Sprint sprint in sprints.value)
    {
        var result = await _importWorkItemService.Post(_sprintCreationURL, GetJsonContent(sprint));
        await _importSprintService.Post(_sprintPublishURL, GetJsonContent(new { id = result.identifier }));
    }
}
```

- I'm not sure whether this `_importWorkItemService.Post(_sprintCreationURL, GetJsonContent(sprint)` should be called on `_importWorkItemService` or on `_importSprintService`

  - Without knowing the actual implementation I can't tell but it is likely a bug in your code

### `CreateWorkItems` method

- Since `CreateWorkItem` should be an `async` method (*see next section*) that's why this should be `async` as well
- I've renamed your `workItemCollection` to `workItems` since you had a `sprints` parameter in `CreateSprints`

```
private async Task CreateWorkItems(Dictionary<string, WorkItemQueryResult> workItems)
{
    foreach (var workItemCategory in workItems.Keys)
    {
        var categoryURL = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/%24{workItemCategory}{_versionQueryString}";

        foreach (var workItem in workItems[workItemCategory].workItems)
        {
            await CreateWorkItem(categoryURL, workItem);
        }
    }
}
```

### `CreateWorkItem` method

- The `GetCurrentIdEquivalentId` and `TryAddIdMapper` can be inlined since they are not complex and they are used only inside the `CreateWorkItem` method once
- You can use the [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) to populate your `operations` List

```
var operations = new List<WorkItemOperation>
{
    new WorkItemOperation()
    {
        path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.Title",
        value = workItem.details.fields.Title ?? ""
    },
    new WorkItemOperation()
    {
        path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.Description",
        value = workItem.details.fields.Description ?? ""
    },
    new WorkItemOperation()
    {
        path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
        value = workItem.details.fields.AcceptanceCriteria ?? ""
    },
    new WorkItemOperation()
    {
        path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.IterationPath",
        value = workItem.details.fields.IterationPath.Replace(_devopsConfiguration.Source.ProjectName, _devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectName)
    }
};
```

- Please prefer `await` over `.Result`

```
await _importWorkItemService.Post(categoryURL, GetJsonContent(operations, "application/json-patch+json"));
```

### `FindParentId` method

- This can be simplified by using the `?.` and `?:` operators

```
private int FindParentId(WorkItemDetails details)
{
    var parentRelation = details.relations?.Where(relation => relation.attributes.name.Equals("Parent")).FirstOrDefault();
    return parentRelation == null ? 0 : int.Parse(parentRelation.url.Split("/")[parentRelation.url.Split("/").Length - 1]);
}
```

- Please note that the `int.Parse` is error-prone, please prefer `int.TryParse` instead

---

For the sake of completeness here is the full code after refactoring

```
class ImportFactory : IImportFactory
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> idMapper = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
    private readonly ILogger<ImportFactory> _logger;
    private readonly Devops _devopsConfiguration;
    private readonly IImportService<WorkItemCore> _importWorkItemService;
    private readonly IImportService<SprintCore> _importSprintService;

    private readonly string _versionQueryString;
    private readonly string _sprintCreationURL;
    private readonly string _sprintPublishURL;
    private readonly string _projectId;
    private const string WorkItemPathPrefix = "/fields/";

    public ImportFactory(ILogger<ImportFactory> logger,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IImportService<SprintCore> importSprintService,
        IImportService<WorkItemCore> importWorkItemService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _devopsConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(nameof(Devops)).Get<Devops>();
        _importSprintService = importSprintService;
        _importWorkItemService = importWorkItemService;

        _versionQueryString = $"?api-version={_devopsConfiguration.APIVersion}";
        _projectId = _devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectId;
        _sprintCreationURL = $"{_projectId}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations{_versionQueryString}";
        _sprintPublishURL = $"{_projectId}/{_devopsConfiguration.Target.TargetTeamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations{_versionQueryString}";
    }

    public async Task<Board> Import(IFormFile file)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
        string fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Board>(fileContent);

        await CreateSprints(board.sprints);
        await CreateWorkItems(board.workItemCollection);

        return board;
    }

    private async Task CreateSprints(Sprints sprints)
    {
        foreach (Sprint sprint in sprints.value)
        {
            var result = await _importWorkItemService.Post(_sprintCreationURL, GetJsonContent(sprint));
            await _importSprintService.Post(_sprintPublishURL, GetJsonContent(new { id = result.identifier }));
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateWorkItems(Dictionary<string, WorkItemQueryResult> workItems)
    {
        foreach (var workItemCategory in workItems.Keys)
        {
            var categoryURL = $"{_projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/%24{workItemCategory}{_versionQueryString}";

            foreach (var workItem in workItems[workItemCategory].workItems)
            {
                await CreateWorkItem(categoryURL, workItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateWorkItem(string categoryURL, WorkItem workItem)
    {
        var operations = new List<WorkItemOperation>
        {
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.Title",
                value = workItem.details.fields.Title ?? ""
            },
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.Description",
                value = workItem.details.fields.Description ?? ""
            },
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
                value = workItem.details.fields.AcceptanceCriteria ?? ""
            },
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.IterationPath",
                value = workItem.details.fields.IterationPath.Replace(_devopsConfiguration.Source.ProjectName, _devopsConfiguration.Target.ProjectName)
            }
        };

        var parentId = FindParentId(workItem.details);
        if (parentId != 0)
        {
            operations.Add(new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = "/relations/-",
                value = new Relationship()
                {
                    url = $"{_devopsConfiguration.Target.DevOpsOrgURL}{_projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/{idMapper[parentId]}",
                    attributes = new RelationshipAttribute()
                }
            });
        }

        var result = await _importWorkItemService.Post(categoryURL, GetJsonContent(operations, "application/json-patch+json"));

        if (!idMapper.ContainsKey(workItem.id))
        {
            idMapper.TryAdd(workItem.id, result.id);
        }
    }

    private int FindParentId(WorkItemDetails details)
    {
        var parentRelation = details.relations?.Where(relation => relation.attributes.name.Equals("Parent")).FirstOrDefault();
        return parentRelation == null ? 0 : int.Parse(parentRelation.url.Split("/")[parentRelation.url.Split("/").Length - 1]);
    }

    private HttpContent GetJsonContent(object data, string mediaType = "application/json")
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        return new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain so thoroughly.