# Azure DevOps Git: Fork into another Repo using Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Azure DevOps Project, I have a Git repository that I would like to copy to another Azure DevOps Project.

In other words, I should be able to copy the original repo into other Azure DevOps projects as needed.

To import work items into Azure DevOps, I have written the following code.

Would you be able to review and make suggestions? Especially, I want to optimize the way HttpClient is being passed to the core service layer from the controller..

Part of this code is already reviewed as you see in this post - [Export and import work items from Azure DevOps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279976/export-and-import-work-items-from-azure-devops).

**Note:**

- Since the destination and/or source of the HttpClient changes every time, I would get the details from the payload.
- At times, the Post method has to return "id" as int/string/nothing.

```
public class ImportController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<ImportController> _logger;
    private readonly IImportFactory _importFactory;

    public ImportController(ILogger<ImportController> logger, IImportFactory importFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _importFactory = importFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImportData([FromForm]ImportData importData)
    {
        _importFactory.Initialize(importData.devOpsProjectSettings);
        await _importFactory.Import(importData.file);

        return Ok();
    }
}
    
public interface IImportService<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> Post(string uri, HttpContent content);
    void SetHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient);
}

public class ImportService<T> : BaseService<T>, IImportService<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<ImportService<T>> _logger;

    public ImportService(ILogger<ImportService<T>> logger) : base()
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<T> Post(string uri, HttpContent content)
    {
        var result = await SendRequest(uri, content);

        return result;
    }

    public void SetHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this._httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}

public class SprintCore
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class WorkItemCore
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string identifier { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceEndpointCore
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}   

    
public class ImportFactory : IImportFactory
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> idMapper = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
    private readonly ILogger<ImportFactory> _logger;
    private readonly DevOps _devopsConfiguration;
    private readonly IImportService<WorkItemCore> _importWorkItemService;
    private readonly IImportService<SprintCore> _importSprintService;
    private readonly IImportService<ServiceEndpointCore> _importRepositoryService;
    private const string WorkItemPathPrefix = "/fields/";
    private readonly string _versionQueryString;

    private DevOpsProjectSettings _devOpsProjectSettings { get; set; }
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private string _sprintCreationURL;
    private string _sprintPublishURL;
    private string _projectId;
    private string _repositoryCreationURL;

    public ImportFactory(ILogger<ImportFactory> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IImportService<SprintCore> importSprintService, IImportService<WorkItemCore> importWorkItemService, IImportService<ServiceEndpointCore> importRepositoryService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _devopsConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(nameof(DevOps)).Get<DevOps>();
        _importSprintService = importSprintService;
        _importWorkItemService = importWorkItemService;
        _importRepositoryService = importRepositoryService;
        _versionQueryString = $"?api-version={_devopsConfiguration.APIVersion}";
    }
    
    public void Initialize(DevOpsProjectSettings devOpsProjectSettings)
    {
        _devOpsProjectSettings = devOpsProjectSettings;
        _projectId = devOpsProjectSettings.ProjectId;
        _sprintCreationURL = $"{_projectId}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations{_versionQueryString}";
        _sprintPublishURL = $"{_projectId}/{devOpsProjectSettings.TeamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations{_versionQueryString}";
        _repositoryCreationURL = $"_apis/git/repositories{_versionQueryString}";

        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(devOpsProjectSettings.DevOpsOrgURL);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", devOpsProjectSettings.PersonalAccessToken))));

        _importSprintService.SetHttpClient(_httpClient);
        _importWorkItemService.SetHttpClient(_httpClient);
        _importRepositoryService.SetHttpClient(_httpClient);
    }

    public async Task<Board> Import(IFormFile file)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
        string fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Board>(fileContent);

        await CreateSprints(board.sprints);
        await CreateWorkItems(board.workItemCollection);
        await CreateRepositories(board.repositories);
        await ImportRepository(board.repositories, _devOpsProjectSettings);

        return board;
    }

    private async Task ImportRepository(Repositories repositories, DevOpsProjectSettings devOpsProjectSettings)
    {
        var _serviceEndpointImportURL = string.Empty;
        var _serviceEndpointCreationURL = $"_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints{_versionQueryString}";

        foreach (Repository repository in repositories.value)
        {
            _serviceEndpointImportURL = $"{_projectId}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository.name}/importRequests{_versionQueryString}";
            devOpsProjectSettings.serviceEndpoint.name = $"Import_External_Repo_{repository.name}";
            
            devOpsProjectSettings.serviceEndpoint.url = $"{devOpsProjectSettings.DevOpsSourceURL}{Uri.EscapeDataString(repository.name)}";
            devOpsProjectSettings.serviceEndpoint.serviceEndpointProjectReferences[0].name= $"Import_External_Repo_{repository.name}";
            
            var serviceEndpointId = await _importRepositoryService.Post(_serviceEndpointCreationURL, GetJsonContent(devOpsProjectSettings.serviceEndpoint));
            
            var importRepo = new ImportRepo();
            importRepo.parameters.serviceEndpointId = serviceEndpointId.id;
            importRepo.parameters.gitSource.url = devOpsProjectSettings.serviceEndpoint.url;

            await _importRepositoryService.Post(_serviceEndpointImportURL, GetJsonContent(importRepo));
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateRepositories(Repositories repositories)
    {
        foreach (Repository repository in repositories.value)
        {
            repository.project.id = _projectId;
            await _importSprintService.Post(_repositoryCreationURL, GetJsonContent(repository));
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateSprints(Sprints sprints)
    {
        foreach (Sprint sprint in sprints.value)
        {
            var result = await _importWorkItemService.Post(_sprintCreationURL, GetJsonContent(sprint));
            await _importSprintService.Post(_sprintPublishURL, GetJsonContent(new { id = result.identifier }));
        }
    }
    private async Task CreateWorkItems(Dictionary<string, WorkItemQueryResult> workItems)
    {
        foreach (var workItemCategory in workItems.Keys)
        {
            var categoryURL = $"{_projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/%24{workItemCategory}{_versionQueryString}";

            foreach (var workItem in workItems[workItemCategory].workItems)
            {
                await CreateWorkItem(categoryURL, workItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateWorkItem(string categoryURL, WorkItem workItem)
    {
        var operations = new List<WorkItemOperation>
        {
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.Title",
                value = workItem.details.fields.Title ?? ""
            },
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.Description",
                value = workItem.details.fields.Description ?? ""
            },
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
                value = workItem.details.fields.AcceptanceCriteria ?? ""
            },
            new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = $"{WorkItemPathPrefix}System.IterationPath",
                value = workItem.details.fields.IterationPath.Replace(_devOpsProjectSettings.SourceProjectName, _devOpsProjectSettings.TargetProjectName)
            }
        };

        var parentId = FindParentId(workItem.details);
        if (parentId != 0)
        {
            operations.Add(new WorkItemOperation()
            {
                path = "/relations/-",
                value = new Relationship()
                {
                    url = $"{_devOpsProjectSettings.DevOpsOrgURL}{_projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/{idMapper[parentId]}",
                    attributes = new RelationshipAttribute()
                }
            });
        }

        var result = await _importWorkItemService.Post(categoryURL, GetJsonContent(operations, "application/json-patch+json"));

        if (!idMapper.ContainsKey(workItem.id))
        {
            idMapper.TryAdd(workItem.id, result.id);
        }
    }

    private int FindParentId(WorkItemDetails details)
    {
        var parentRelation = details.relations?.Where(relation => relation.attributes.name.Equals("Parent")).FirstOrDefault();
        return parentRelation == null ? 0 : int.Parse(parentRelation.url.Split("/")[parentRelation.url.Split("/").Length - 1]);
    }

    private HttpContent GetJsonContent(object data, string mediaType = "application/json")
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        return new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please amend your post to include the link of your previous question.

Comment: @PeterCsala - included the link to the previous question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, I will get it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `ImportController`

#### `ImportData`

- In software industry the `data` is a magic word for anything

  - Please try to be more precise with naming to bring clarity
- `_importFactory.Initialize` seems pretty weird

  - The `Factory` suffix is usually used when you have applied the [factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

    - Your current naming might be misleading
  - Also be aware of the fact that the compiler can't enforce you to call the `Initialize` before calling the `Import`

    - This makes your code fragile
- As I can see the `Import` method call can throw several different exceptions

  - I hope there is a middleware in your pipeline which logs these exceptions and converts the response to 500
- I would suggest to consider to return with 201 (Created) rather than 200 (Ok)

  - Since you have exposed an Import API that's why it would make sense to confirm that the import has *created* all the resources in the given system with success

### `ImportService`

- Without knowing what `BaseService` does it is impossible to provide insightful suggestions
- Although here are several tiny observations:

  - The `_logger` is not used, just initialized
  - The `string uri` might contain invalid url
  - This `SetHttpClient` feels pretty weird

    - This api allows the consumer of this class to change the `HttpClient` between two `Post` calls
    - Also the compiler can't enforce that you should call the `SetHttpClient` before the call of `Post`
- In your question you have mentioned *the Post method has to return "id" as int/string/nothing*

  - But you have restricted `T` to be a `class`, so you can't use `int` as type parameter

### `SprintCore`, ... , `ServiceEndpointCore`

- Please prefer C# naming convention for your public properties

  - Please prefer `Id` over `id`
  - Or use `JsonPropertyAttribute` for renaming (if needed at all)
- What does this `Core` suffix mean?

  - They all look like DTO classes

### `ImportFactory`

- Since I have reviewed the majority of this class in your previous post that's why I will try to focus only on the new stuff

#### `Initialize`

- As I have stated several times this `Initialize` "pattern" makes your code fragile, since you can't enforce the call of this method prior any other publicly exposed method
- I'm not sure which .NET version are you using but if not the recent ones then please consider to use `IHttpClientFactory` to create a new `HttpClient` instance
- Please prefer `Uri.TryCreate` over `new Uri` to parse `string` as `Uri`
- Please try to avoid basic auth (`AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic" ...`) since it is not secure by any means

#### `ImportRepository`

- It is unnecessary to pass the `_devOpsProjectSettings` field as a parameter since this method can access that as well
- Also please adjust naming

  - It imports repositories, not just a single one
- The `_serviceEndpointCreationURL` can be constructed only once, there is no need to regenerate it every time when this method is being called
- `ImportRepo`: Please try to avoid any unnecessary abbreviations `Repo` >> `Repository`

### `CreateRepositories`

- It might make sense to combine this method with the `ImportRepositories` since you iterate through the same collection